# DLL and TLB referenced issue in Excel VBA

Tags: .net, excel, vba, dll, typelib

I Created a '**Sample.Dll**' and '**sample.tlb**' file containing a function which returns a value, using Visual Studio 2005 class library for access it in the Microsoft Office Excel's Macro to getting a cells value.

I Set some properties in visual studio 2005 before building the Solution.the Changes are:

> - Application -->Assembly Information-->Make Assembly COM visible Check box Checked.
> - Compile --> Register for COM interop Check box Checked(Which creates 'Sample.tlb' file)
> - Signing --> Sign the Assembly.Check Box Checked(Which creates 'Sample.snk' file)

I Build the Solution and There is three files in the Release folder

> - Sample.Dll
> - Sample.tlb
> - Sample.snk
> - sample.Pdb
> - sample.xml

Now i place the '**sample.dll**' and '**sample.tlb**' in the System32 then register the sample.dll on the another machine two times

> 1. by gacutil /i sample.dll
> 2. by RegAsm sample.dll

Now I Open the Excel then Create a Macro and add a reference of the 'sample.tlb' from system 32 and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library and Microsoft DAO 3.6 Library.
now i create a object of the class file of the DLL.

```
Cells(1,1)=object.Function()
```

It returns value in the same machine where the sample.Dll build but on another machine it gives an error when executes the Function and did not return the value of that cells.
the function gave Error Code.

> 1.Error Code 429
>   2.Error Code -2147024894

I researched on that two error but did not got any strong result.
why it occurs in any other machine where i did not compile sample.dll?
how to create a universal Dll which run perfectly in each and Every machine configuration?. 
or What step I did not perform ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are hitting a problem because the other machines don't have office on them.  You have to have office for the Office Interop DLLs to work.  Take a look at:

http://debugmode.net/2011/08/28/creating-and-updating-excel-file-in-windows-azure-web-role-using-open-xml-sdk/

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank You very much for the feedback. Yes, ofcourse Office needs to be installed on the Destination machine and we have ensured that for sure. Still the problem is persisting. Please, kindly help us address this issue. We hope we are able to convey the problem that we are facing. Please, kindly let us know if any further details are required for us to convey you the problem that we are facing.